# Constructing an algebraic extension of degree n of $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to explicitly formulate an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of degree $n$, and my guess is that factoring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by the polynomial $x^n-2$ would serve its job. I know that the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ by the Eisenstein criterion, but am wondering how I would prove the irreducibility of $x^n-2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Is my guess correct? Should I instead factor $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}_p$ with $x^{p^n} -x$ or something...?

**Edit**

I changed the title of my question from "Is $x^n-2$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?" to "constructing an algebraic extension of degree n of $\mathbb{Z}_p$," the finite field of order $p$. I know that $x^n-2$ is not always irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ now. How can I construct an algebraic extension?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb Z_p$?  That notation could be ambiguous.  I suppose you mean $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.   $x^2-2$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I meant the finite field of prime characteristic p

Comment: There are plenty of finite fields for each prime characteristic. I suppose you meant the finite field of order $p$.

Comment: There are many counterexamples.

Comment: @Peter You are right. I just figured out $x^2-2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ is reducible.

Comment: $x^n-2$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$

Comment: I would strongly urge you to use $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbf{F}_p$ for this field (also in use, $\mathrm{GF}(p)$, for "Galois field of order $p$"), because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ may be misunderstood to be the [$p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#p-adic_integers).

Comment: The (unique) extension of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the (unique up to isomorphism) field of order $p^n$. It is the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I said it is **reducible**

Comment: @jjagmath: I may need new glasses... sorry.